# Sudden Break in the while loop in Program to find Factors

Tags: c++, math, while-loop, nested-loops, computation

I was writing a code that calculates the two factors of any given number using two nested 'While' loops but after just one iteration the loop just stops

**Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
long int Password;

void main()
{ 
    long int n=2,n1=2;
    cout<<"Type the number whose factor you need"<<endl;
    cin>>Password;
    while( n <  3600 )
    { 
        while( n1 < 3600 )
        {
            if( n*n1 == Password )
            {
                cout<<"your Factors are "<<n<<" and "<<n1<<endl;
                getch();
            }
            else
            {
                n1++; 
                break;
            }
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Output is only working for small numbers but when a little big numbers are inserted the program terminates. I am not understanding the problem as the code is perfectly fine. Am I having a less powerful processor?

Comment: Does this compile? Always use braces - prevents errors

Comment: @EdHeal Yes the program builds in VS and compiles in Turbo C++

Comment: The `break;` needs to run if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: For C++ it should be `int main()`

Comment: And also, Why is the question down voted? Is it out of context?

Comment: Also, and this is pure efficiency talk, when you're in the first `while` statement, you know the value of `n` and you have `Password` - why are you looping from 2 to 3600 again. `n2 = Password / n`...

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime It's just not a very good question. There is almost no connection between the code given and the question asked. The closest we have to an actual question is the last sentence, which seems to come out of nowhere and has no context in the other parts of the question. Also, you've neither shown any effort debugging the program nor asked how to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is not calculating the factors of any given number. Also, naming the number "Password" is confusing.

Maybe you want something like this in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int number;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer whose factors you need: " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    cout << "Factors of " << number << " are ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        if (number % i == 0)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

As was noted in the comments, in C++ you have `int main()` not `void main()`, even though some compilers do support `void main()`.